# Error Querying a table using ADODB with VBA in Excel

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

I am attempting to use SQL to query a table (Purchases) in Excel. However, I get an error when the script below is run.

The tableaddress variable produces Purchases!$A$2:$F$1200 which is the range of the table "Purchases".

The SQL query that is produced is:

```
Select * From [Purchases!$A$2:$F$1200]
```

The current VBA itself is as shown below:

```
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim tableAddress As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name

    cn.Open
    tableAddress = "Purchases!" & Range("Purchases").Address
    strSQL = "Select * From [" & tableAddress & "]"
    rs.Open strSQL, cn
    cn.Close
```

However, when executing I get the error below...

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] 'Purchases!$A$2:$F$1200' is not a valid name.
Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is no too long.
```

I see the apostrophes in the error but am not sure if that's the punctuation being referred to or how to get rid of it if so.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try without the `[]`?

Comment: I have, that produces a 'Syntax error in FROM clause' issue. I originally had it that way but added the brackets after I saw those referenced in other instructions on ADODB.

Comment: what about the `ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name`. Are you sure the `ActiveWorkbook` is the one you think it is and that is has a `Purchases` tab in it? Also try qualifing the full file path in the SQL statement.
`

Comment: I tried those by bringing that out to a MsgBox and can confirm that it is referencing the correct workbook. I also just tried hard-coding the path and it produced the same result. This one is a little bizarre because I've been able to produce SQL scripts like this successfully in the past but this one is deciding to complicate things!

Comment: Is there a reason to use `ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name` rather than just `ActiveWorkbook.Fullname`?

Comment: I've tried it both ways and it produces the same error. I chose to use the complex version because this file will end up moving about on many different file servers/computers/versions and figured that might be the safest path, I wouldn't object to modifying it however.

Comment: I assume `tableAddress = "Purchases"` works.

Comment: Trying that modification leads to a "Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Purchases'" error, which would have initially led me to believe the path was wrong, but using MsgBox to show the path confirms that it's at least pulling that correctly. I assume I'm doing something stupid and something simple is wrong but my mind is blind to it right now.

Comment: I'm surprised just pointing to a range doesn't work - that's what I always use in my macros.  I thought the fact that the range name and the sheet name were identical may have been causing the issues, but I just tested that and it was OK.  I have posted an answer showing the correct syntax for supplying both the sheet name and the range area to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim tableAddress As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name

cn.Open
tableAddress = "Purchases$" & Range("Purchases").Address(False, False)
strSQL = "Select * From [" & tableAddress & "]"
rs.Open strSQL, cn
cn.Close
```

Comment: Good one on the `$`. I knew there was a certain trick here that I was forgetting!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I had to google it to find the answer - I always just use a straight range name when specifying the source area.

Comment: This is perfect! I knew I was missing something simple. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Quick question that I don't think I need another whole session for. How would I add a "HDR=No" portion to this appropriately. It keeps registering the second line of the table as the first and the first line as the header. Thanks!

Comment: @WSwanson - Using `cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;"";"` I could get it to return the first row of the source range .... providing that row contains numeric values.